# If statements vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Just started programming. About 3 months into it. Was wondering whats wrong with this code. The axwindow.url is the song that is currently playing so depending on which song it is it will ask a different question.

```
     Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Hide()
    TextBox2.Hide()
    TextBox3.Hide()
    Label3.Text = "0"
    username = InputBox("What is your name?")
    Label2.Text = username + after
    If Form1.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = champs Then
        Label1.Text = "Who is the song We are the Champions by?"
        TextBox1.Show()
    End If
    If Form1.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = rag Then
        Label1.Text = "Who is the song Maple Leaf Rag by?"
        TextBox2.Show()
    End If
    If Form1.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = pianoman Then
        Label1.Text = "Who is the song Piano Man by?"
        TextBox3.Show()
    End If
    Button1.Hide()

End Sub





Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If Form1.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = champs And TextBox1.Text = "Queen" Then
        TextBox1.Text = "Correct!"
        CheckBox1.Hide()
        Button1.Show()
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "Worng answer"
        CheckBox1.CheckState = False
    End If
    If Form1.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = rag And TextBox2.Text = "Scott Joplin" Then
        TextBox2.Text = "Correct!"
        CheckBox1.Hide()
        Button1.Show()
    Else
        TextBox2.Text = "Worng answer"
        CheckBox1.CheckState = False

    End If
    If Form1.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = pianoman And TextBox3.Text = "Billy Joel" Then
        TextBox3.Text = "Correct!"
        CheckBox1.Hide()
        Button1.Show()
    Else
        TextBox3.Text = "Worng answer"
        CheckBox1.CheckState = False

    End If
    If TextBox1.Text <> "Queen" Or TextBox1.Text <> "Scott Joplin" Or TextBox1.Text <> "Billy Joel" Then
        TextBox1.Text = "Wrong answer"
        CheckBox1.CheckState = False
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "Correct!"
    End If

End Sub
```

For some reason when i write Scott Joplin in the textbox it says correct and shows button one but when i put down Queen or Billy Joel for the other two questions it says wrong answer but still hides the checkbox and shows the button.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: set a breakpoint and watch which statements/blocks execute.  you'll learn a lot about the difference between what you *thought* you coded vs what you actually coded. (hint: a correct answer is overwritten by the last `If` block because it will always execute)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

    If Form1.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = champs And TextBox1.Text = "Queen" Then
        TextBox1.Text = "Correct!"
        CheckBox1.Hide()  
        Button1.Show()
        Exit Sub
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "Worng answer"
        CheckBox1.CheckState = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Form1.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = rag And TextBox2.Text = "Scott Joplin" Then
        TextBox2.Text = "Correct!"
        CheckBox1.Hide()
        Button1.Show()
        Exit Sub
    Else
        TextBox2.Text = "Worng answer"
        CheckBox1.CheckState = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Form1.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = pianoman And TextBox3.Text = "Billy Joel" Then
        TextBox3.Text = "Correct!"
        CheckBox1.Hide()
        Button1.Show()
        Exit Sub
    Else
        TextBox3.Text = "Worng answer"
        CheckBox1.CheckState = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text <> "Queen" Or TextBox1.Text <> "Scott Joplin" Or TextBox1.Text <> "Billy Joel" Then
        TextBox1.Text = "Wrong answer"
        CheckBox1.CheckState = False
        Exit Sub
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "Correct!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Try putting Exit Sub On Every Condition so the other "IF" Condition will not Executed...

Comment: ah im still coming up with wrong answer even though the right things are happening after i put in the exit sub

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured out what i did wrong. When i ran the program it was running line by line so even if i wasn't trying to answer the queen question it was going to else right away before it read anything else. Thanks for telling me about the breakpoints really helpful.

```
                                                  ,Nate
```